# Can somebody provide an example for using javascript api to insert a comment to a file in drive?

Tags: google-drive-api

Can somebody provide an example for using javascript api to insert a comment to a file in drive?

I tried; however I got error response saying application/json is not allowed.

Thanks in advance.

============
I did some guesswork after sending this question.

It worked with following code.

```
function insertComment (fileObj)
{
  var fileId = fileObj['id'];

  var request = gapi.client.request(
    { 'path': '/drive/v2/files/'+ fileId + '/comments',
      'method': 'POST',
      'body': { content : "testing comment from js" }
    }
  );
  request.execute(insertCommentResult);
}
```

/upload/... was the error .... it seems that works only for media upload.
Thanks for your support. (It took me a while to get used to the formatting of stackoveflow :) )

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: It helps if you add what you tried...

Comment: function insertComment (fileObj)
{
  var fileId = fileObj['id'];
  var commentBody = {
    content : "testing comment from js"
  };
  var request = gapi.client.request({
    'path': '/upload/drive/v2/files/'+ fileId + '/comments',
      'method': 'POST',
      'body':{
        content : "testing comment from js"
      }
  });

  request.execute(insertCommentResult);
}

Comment: I did some guesswork.  It worked with following code.

function insertComment (fileObj)
{
  var fileId = fileObj['id'];
  var commentBody = {
    content : "testing comment from js"
  };

  var request = gapi.client.request({
    'path': '/drive/v2/files/'+ fileId + '/comments',
      'method': 'POST',
      'body':{
        content : "testing comment from js"
      }
  });

  request.execute(insertCommentResult);
}

Comment: Please put your code in the question.

Comment: Done as per above instruction. Thanks.

Comment: Great, if this is solved, can you put your correct code in an answer?